# Facebook Login Button Appears Over Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement the [facebook login tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook), along with a navigation drawer. I managed to create the drawer successfully, but when I tried it on the emulator, the facebook login button appears over the drawer, even though it is part of another layout (fragment).
Here's my MainActivity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#ff939393"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#ff333333"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is my fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/facebook_login_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="312dp"
    android:layout_height="101dp"
    android:text="@string/please_login_with_facebook"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_weight="0.13"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

<Button android:id="@+id/connection_settings_button"
    android:layout_width="188dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/turn_on_internet_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] mDrawerTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private FacebookLoginFragment fbFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

    mDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        fbFragment = new FacebookLoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fbFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        fbFragment = (FacebookLoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}


private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mDrawerTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I'll post more code if necessary. Unfortunately I still don't have the reputation to post images, but [here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igEez.jpg). Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `FragmentTransaction.replace` your `FacebookLoginFragment`, don't use the id `android.R.id.content`. Instead use the id of the `FrameLayout` that acts as the content of your `DrawerLayout`, which in this case is `R.id.content_frame`.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I have been busy. Thank you once again!